# Vue-material Object.values is not a function error in ipad 4

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

I created vue app using vue-cli and added vue-material 1.0 beta dependency.
I created a simple form using vue-material. It works fine on new mobile or desktop browsers but fails on ipad 4 browser both safari and chrome. I got this error from safari on ipad 4 and page is blank:

> TypeError: Object.values is not a function. (In
>   'Object.values(MdComponents)', 'Object.values' is undefined)

I tried to  add polyfill for Object.values  but it does not make any difference.

Comment: Did you make an issue on github? It seems like a problem in vue-material.

Comment: @Craig I could not find how to report this issue on github. I was looking for it but did not find where to report this.

Comment: Maybe check through https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues to see if there is not something there that is relative to this issue, if not create a new issue (button top right once logged in i think)